# Create a generic type parameterized by a number

Tags: generics, rust

I'm writing an NGram library in Rust. I want to create a 'generic' ngram where the size doesn't need to be determined until compilation time (as opposed to when I code it). A little code might help make that clear.

Here is basically what I want to be able to do:

```
pub type Ngram<N> = Vec<[String; N]>;
```

and then to use it, you simply do something like this:

```
let vec = Ngram::<5>::new();
```

And you would have created a five-gram (or more precisely, a `Vec<[String; 5]>`). Is something like that possible. I really don't want to do something like this:

```
 pub type Ngram<N> = Vec<N>;
 ...
 let vec = Ngram::<[String; 5]>::new();
```

That would mostly defeat the purpose of creating the type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be possible in the future, but until then, the best way to do it is:

Use a base trait for a fixed size array, implement it with macros for all the sizes you need. With the trait, you don't need more macros for the rest of the functionality.

In normal use I bet that you don't have to type `let vec = Ngram::<[String; 5]>::new();`, you can just say:

```
let vec = Ngram::<[_; 5]>::new();
```

which is slightly better. If you use your supporting trait to constrain the array's element type to `String`, then this writing is never ambiguous.

See the [crate arrayvec's code](https://github.com/bluss/arrayvec) for more info.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't possible in Rust 1.0. The size of an array can't be generic.

Comment: However, it may be possible to achieve the equivalent by writing a macro, as with the standard vec!

Comment: @trentcl Yeah, I think that's what I'll have to do. I also found https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1038 which seems to be exactly what I'm talking about. Hopefully some day it will be implemented.

Comment: @dobafresh: It is very much desired, and intimately linked to compile-time function evaluation (as having just raw numbers without the ability to modify them is not as useful).